# Can someone explain what this regexp_substr is doing(oracle)

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I have a swift message like this

```
"{1:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}{2:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}{4:
 :20:M000000043319452
 :25:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkUR
 :28C:00037/00012
 :60M:FGHYYGGGG,52
 :61:1402210221CR180,ABCDEFGHIJK//25-15974720-2}
```

So i used the following to extract the value 00012 from the 28C tag. But i'm not able to understand how it's actually working.Please help with the details

```
regexp_substr(msgswi, ':28C:.*?/(\S*)', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Break down the pattern. It's pretty simple.

- `:28C:` matches exactly those four characters.
- `.*?` matches zero or more characters (any character), non-greedily.
- `/` matches exactly one forward slash character.
- `(\S*)` matches **and captures** zero or more non-whitespace character.

So in this case,  you've got the following matches between the input and the pattern:

- `:28C:` matches `:28C:`
- `00037` matches `.*?`
- `/` matches `/`
- `00012` matches `\S*`

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt.. Clearly underdstood now :)